# Как найти маленькое изображение на большом и получить его координаты?

Tags: java, изображения, поиск, нейронные-сети

Задача такая: есть скриншот экрана, и изображение (в частности кнопки), нужно найти координаты изображения (например левого верхнего угла) и произвести клик по этим координатам (по кнопке)

Comment: Можно попробовать с помощью [OpenCV](http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/08-object-detection.html)

Comment: Мало информации (точнее она перемешена) - фиксированный ли скриншот, есть ли масштабирование, подозреваю, что применение OpenCV и нейросетей - скорее из пушки по воробьям. Потом в чем проблема в поиске изображения (это одна задача) или "произвести клик по области" - это другая. И вообще где вариант Вашего решения.

Comment: скиншот фиксированный, маштабирования нет. В том то и дело, что я хочу найти оптиматьное решение

Comment: Если скриншот фиксирован, то кто Вам мешает заранее определить координаты зон в пикселях, которые соответствуют Вашим органам управления, и дальше контролировать в какой из зон находится мышь. В довиндовую эпоху (MS-DOS) именно так делался весь навороченный графический интерфейс.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать этот инструмент **[Online Photo Editor](https://pixlr.com/editor/)**. После загрузки изображения в правой панели, сверху, имеется навигатор. Щелкайте по требуемым точкам вашего изображения и в навигаторе отражаются координаты этой точки на изображении. К координатам требуемой точке вы можете установить кнопку или линк для перехода куда-то далее по вашему выбору.